# AWS RDS to Kinesis data stream to Lambda - decrypting records

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-rds, amazon-kinesis

Summary: I am trying to descrypt "databaseActivityEvents" that are streamed from AWS RDS to Kinesis to Lambda function. No matter how I try to decrypt the data is always returns "InvalidCiphertextException: null"

Detail:

1. created new aurora database cluster
2. created a customer managed key using SYMMETRIC_DEFAULT in KMS
3. created new kinesis data stream using above key and attached to the aurora db cluster
4. created a lambda that is triggered by the kinesis data stream and is sent a json "event"

All of this is working. I do a console log of the event in lambda and I am getting data base events, mostly heart beats, but all of this above is working. This is a sample event (all data is in dev so I dont mind showing actual data)

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "kinesis": {
        "kinesisSchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "partitionKey": "05841e02-874c-4628-b79e-1dcd5d73b256",
        "sequenceNumber": "49639037278219440985425171458121310232781924676881350674",
        "data": "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",
        "approximateArrivalTimestamp": 1679260829.009
      },
      "eventSource": "aws:kinesis",
      "eventVersion": "1.0",
      "eventID": "shardId-000000000001:49639037278219440985425171458121310232781924676881350674",
      "eventName": "aws:kinesis:record",
      "invokeIdentityArn": "arn:aws:iam::767437170311:role/lambda-admin",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
      "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:kinesis:us-east-1:767437170311:stream/aws-rds-das-cluster-6KXUII5RDIBDAE6U7EQLZST2YI"
    }
  ]
}
```

I then run this code to decode the .data field

```
    const raw = Buffer.from(record.kinesis.data, 'base64').toString('ascii')
    const json = JSON.parse(raw)
```

and this is the json variable:

```
{
  type: 'DatabaseActivityMonitoringRecords',
  version: '1.2',
  databaseActivityEvents: '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',
  key: 'AQIDAHhqWGCvn9ocP1RukzEKLPjWzOVL6Asy4R2YSnFP47SOywG3F1wvThSP2mLy9E0NKUEpAAAAfjB8BgkqhkiG9w0BBwagbzBtAgEAMGgGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQM2zIiDuB91ei9IzzCAgEQgDuT8yDHCZ0wLqcV5Pknkc/CgIoJh9SXqrPdxpQDxh2f1VrWxdHvKl44tf89BBi39MYuboXID9sA4F2GVg=='
}
```

Now I run this code:

```
const databaseActivityEvents = Buffer.from(json.databaseActivityEvents, 'base64')

    const params = {
      KeyId: "c4d1dc19-ce04-4568-9863-d80ec0ff4c58",
      CiphertextBlob: databaseActivityEvents,
      EncryptionContext: {
        "aws:rds:dbc-id": "cluster-DFGNFSATIUGUYQA5DDCCJWTXCQ"
      } 
    }

    const results = await kms.decrypt(params).promise()
    console.log(results.Plaintext.toString('ascii'))
```

This throws an error of InvalidCiphertextException. In the params above I include and exclude the `EncryptionContext` attribute and get same result. I have seen that EncryptionContext key and value in many samples (I am using my cluster name not one in samples I have seen)

Lastly, important, this code runs fine

```
 let params = {
    KeyId: "c4d1dc19-ce04-4568-9863-d80ec0ff4c58",
    Plaintext: 'Test Ecrypt Me',
    EncryptionContext: {
      "Test": "EncryptionContext123"
    }
  }

  let results = await kms.encrypt(params).promise()

  console.log(results.CiphertextBlob)

  params = {
    KeyId: "c4d1dc19-ce04-4568-9863-d80ec0ff4c58",
    CiphertextBlob: results.CiphertextBlob,
    EncryptionContext: {
      "Test": "EncryptionContext123"
    }
  }

  results = await kms.decrypt(params).promise()
  console.log(results.Plaintext.toString('ascii'))
```

which outputs good data

```
<Buffer 01 02 02 00 78 6a 58 60 af 9f da 1c 3f 54 6e 93 31 0a 2c f8 d6 cc e5 4b e8 0b 32 e1 1d 98 4a 71 4f e3 b4 8e cb 01 af 6a 37 6d 29 90 d2 f3 c8 b5 45 f9 ... 116 more bytes>

Test Ecrypt Me
```

I have searched for weeks on this, I cannot find a good working example in javascript.

I do not know how or where in kineses (or if) the EncryptionContext is getting set so I am unsure how to check what it is if it even is happening when kineses stream is getting sent to lambda.

How do I properly decrypt databaseActivityEvents which should contain records of updates from my RDS instance?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got something working, be sure to replace the `"cluster-xxxxxxxxxxx"` with your RDS cluster ID, NOT resource id, the cluster id

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const {
    RawAesKeyringNode,
    RawAesWrappingSuiteIdentifier,
    buildClient,
    KmsKeyringNode,
    KmsKeyringBrowser,
    encryptionSdk,
    CommitmentPolicy
} = require('@aws-crypto/client-node')
aws.config.logger = console;
const zlib = require("zlib");
const { encrypt, decrypt } = buildClient(
 CommitmentPolicy.REQUIRE_ENCRYPT_ALLOW_DECRYPT
);

console.log('Loading function');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const kms = new aws.KMS({ region: "us-east-1" });
    try {
        const output = await Promise.all(
            event.Records.map(async (record) => {
               // console.log(record.kinesis.data);
                const data = Buffer.from(record.kinesis.data, 'base64');
                const record_data = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(record_data);
                const payload_decoded = Buffer.from(record_data.databaseActivityEvents, 'base64');
                const data_key_decoded = Buffer.from(record_data.key, 'base64');
                const data_key_decrypt_result = await kms.decrypt({
                    CiphertextBlob: data_key_decoded,
                    EncryptionContext: {
                        "aws:rds:dbc-id": "cluster-xxxxxxxxxxx",
                    }
                }).promise();
                //console.log(typeof data_key_decrypt_result.Plaintext, data_key_decrypt_result.Plaintext);
                const wrappingSuite = RawAesWrappingSuiteIdentifier.AES256_GCM_IV12_TAG16_NO_PADDING;
                const unencryptedMasterKey = new Uint8Array(data_key_decrypt_result.Plaintext);
               // console.log(unencryptedMasterKey.byteLength);
               // console.log(data_key_decrypt_result.Plaintext)

                const keyring = new RawAesKeyringNode({
                    keyName: "DataKey",
                    keyNamespace: "BC",
                    wrappingSuite: wrappingSuite,
                    unencryptedMasterKey: unencryptedMasterKey,
                });

                const { plaintext, messageHeader } = await decrypt(keyring, record_data.databaseActivityEvents, {encoding: 'base64'});
                //const events = JSON.parse(plaintext);
                console.log(plaintext)
                // not functioning 
                const decompressed = zlib.unzip(plaintext, (err, buffer) => {
                    
                      if (!err) {
                          const events = JSON.parse(buffer);
                        console.log(events);
                      } else {
                      }
                      return buffer;
                    });
            })
        );
        console.log(`Processing completed.  Successful records ${output.length}.`);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

sample output

```
{
  type: 'DatabaseActivityMonitoringRecord',
  clusterId: 'cluster-xxxxxxx',
  instanceId: 'db-xxxxxx',
  databaseActivityEventList: [
    {
      logTime: '2023-05-26 05:20:09.61786+00',
      statementId: 17,
      substatementId: 1,
      objectType: 'TABLE',
      command: 'INSERT',
      objectName: 'public.das',
      databaseName: 'mylab',
      dbUserName: 'masteruser',
      remoteHost: '10.0.0.208',
      remotePort: '55236',
      sessionId: '647005e0.3c6',
      rowCount: 1,
      commandText: 'insert into das values(1);',
      paramList: [],
      pid: 966,
      clientApplication: 'psql',
      exitCode: null,
      class: 'WRITE',
      serverVersion: '15.2.1',
      serverType: 'PostgreSQL',
      serviceName: 'Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL-Compatible edition',
      serverHost: '10.0.3.232',
      netProtocol: 'TCP',
      dbProtocol: 'Postgres 3.0',
      type: 'record',
      startTime: '2023-05-26 05:20:09.617855+00',
      errorMessage: null
    }
  ]
}
```